# Wordpress featured image as div background image

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

How can I set the featured images on all my posts to be outputted as a background image to a div. For example

```
<div class="postimg" style="background-image:url('https://s3.amazonaws.com/ooomf-com-files/8jLdwLg6TLKIQfJcZgDb_Freedom_5.jpg')"></div>
```

Currently the featured image is being outputted as a regular image using this helper `<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'wpbs-featured' ); ?>`

Comment: You'd have to edit the_post_thumbnail() function from WordPress files... It is located in: wp-includes/post-thumbnail-template.php.

Comment: @Zerquix18 what do I edit...

Comment: At line 114 in wp-includes/post-thumbnail-template.php replace by `                $html = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumbnail_id, $size, false);`` now $html contains the SRC to the image. You can change make a newline with: `$html = "<div class="postimg" style="background-image:url('$html')"></div>";`

Comment: @Zerquix18 - How did you come to that conclusion? It's just that you are absolutely wrong. I mean way more than 100% wrong. NEVER EVER amend WP core files.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest simply something along the lines of this
Get post featured image URL and echo it out accordingly:

```
<?php
$img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), "full");
$img = $img[0];
?>
<div class="postimg" style="<?php if($img){echo 'background:url('.$img.');';} ?>">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
<div style="background-image:url('<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() );?>')"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
<div id="custom-bg" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')">

</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```